# Apagar a ultima linha de um arquivo txt

Tags: python

Preciso apagar a ultima linha de um arquivo txt.

Encontrei a ultima linha assim:

```
with open('arquivo.txt', 'r') as content:
    line = content.readlines()
    last_line = line[len(line)-1]
```

Obs: pode alterar o modo read na função open.

Comment: Você precisa resolver isso necessariamente com Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para trabalhar com arquivos grandes essa é uma possível solução:

```py
import os

with open('arquivo.txt', 'r+', encoding = "utf-8") as arquivo:

    # Move o ponteiro (similar a um cursor de um editor de textos) para o fim do arquivo. 
    arquivo.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)

    # Pula o ultimo caractere do arquivo
    # No caso de a ultima linha ser null, deletamos a ultima linha e a penúltima
    pos = arquivo.tell() - 1

    # Lê cada caractere no arquivo, um por vez, a partir do penúltimo
    # caractere indo para trás, buscando por um caractere de nova linha
    # Se encontrarmos um nova linha, sai da busca
    while pos > 0 and arquivo.read(1) != "\n":
        pos -= 1
        arquivo.seek(pos, os.SEEK_SET)

    # Enquanto não estivermos no começo do arquivo, deleta todos os caracteres para frente desta posição
    if pos > 0:
        arquivo.seek(pos, os.SEEK_SET)
        arquivo.truncate()
```

Comment: Resposta original: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10289740/1452488

Answer (score 3):

Se for um arquivo muito grande, veja esta forma, ele lê o arquivo de trás pra frente em binário até encontrar o caractere da ultima linha. Depois o converte.

```
import os

with open('arquivo.txt', 'rb') as f:
   f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END)
   while f.read(1) != b'\n':
      f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_CUR) 
   print(f.readline().decode())
```

Answer (score 1):

Se por acaso estivermos em sistemas *nix, uma solução seria

```
head -n -1 file > novo
```

... mas não usa Python.

Answer (score 0):

Desta forma:

```
line = file.readlines()
line = lines[:-1]
```

Comment: Vale notar que isso carregará todo o conteúdo do arquivo em memória. Se estiver trabalhando com arquivos grandes, isso pode ser um problema sério.

Comment: Esse é um dos problemas, o arquivo e grande e preciso minimizar o uso dos recursos.